# Why is asking a question on a meta so hard?

Tags: discussion, user-interface

As far as I can tell, there's no link to metas on the actual SE sites. You have to first click on the "ask a question" link, which for some reason is all the way over to the right despite it being the whole point of the site, and then you have to notice the "Ask it on meta" option over the right, at the bottom of the "How to Ask" box.

Comment: Total mismatch between title and body of your question. First decide what you want to ask, then ask. Title is about asking being hard, body is about not finding the link.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I wanted to ask a question on meta, and it took a lot of effort to do so. I wanted to inquire as to why that was so. "Why is asking a question on a meta so hard?" describes my question. I suppose their is some ambiguity in that it might be understood as "Why is it, once on a meta, to ask a question", rather than the intended "Why is the entire process of asking a meta question so hard?" but other than that, I don't see any mismatch.

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of ambiguities. Also [FYI](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: What about "Where is the link to meta?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you click on the 'hamburger menu' (upper right corner, see first pic below), you will see a menu (second pic below). The first entry on the menu is your current community; immediately below that is the "meta" for that community. If you select the Meta link, you'll be sent to the Meta, which has its own "Ask Question" button, which works just like the regular site.

[image: Icons including Hamburger Menu]

[image: expanded hamburger]

Comment: Whenever I want to go to a meta, I click on my profile, and then "meta user". Works like a charm

Comment: To be fair, this used to be easier with the *really* old top bar (pre-late 2013), when there was a direct link to meta there.

Answer (score 5):

Asking on meta of a specific site, has the same procedure as asking on a regular site. Namely you first have to go to a specific site, and when you press on *ask question* it will automatically bring you to asking the question on the site you were on till now.

To access the Meta site simply press on the stack exchange icon on the top right of the screen, and you'll see an option to visit meta of your site. When in meta, press on *ask question* like you would do on any other site.[image]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the hamburger menu the other answers mention, another way of getting to a meta site is opening one of the "Hot Meta Posts" on the right sidebar. (That is how I usually do it, as it requires one less click.)